# When purchasing a return flight, can I add extra passengers to the return leg?

Tags: air-travel, bookings

I want to book a round-trip flight from Los Angeles to Detroit.

But, while returning my wife and kid will be travelling with me, too.
Is there any way I can book the returning flight including my wife and kid?

I mean, departure flight will have only one (me) passenger but return flight will have three (me, wife, kid) passengers.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this question on this site before, but I can't find the duplicate question now....

Answer (score 7):

You can buy one-way tickets for the return trip for your wife and kid using either miles or money.

Then you can phone the airline and ask them to link your reservations for the return. This will help (but not assure) that there's a modicum of connectivity between your reservations.

Comment: Depending on the airline, you may be able to reserve adjoining seats.

Comment: @Jonas even if it is not possible to reserve adjoining seats, in my experience it is almost always possible to find enough sympathetic travelers to switch so you can sit together.  The only caveat I have is that I've never tried to do that when everyone in my party had a center seat.

Comment: @phoog: True; though sometimes you have to settle on getting some sweet revenge when that lady in the aisle seat absolutely refuses to swap her seat with the aisle seat one row behind her (which would have allowed me to sit next to my kids), and then she is super annoyed throughout the entire flight that my two kids are being kids and go "daddy, daddy, this" and "daddy, daddy, that".